# build new obj with parent information

Tags: grails, groovy, constructor

I dont know if this is possible but what I want to do is:

```
def par = Participant.get(0)
new Winner(par)
```

explaining the code above: Participant is parent class of Winner, so I wanna create a Winner instance but copying all the fields which are filled in that participant.

Is that possible?! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
new Winner(par.properties)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to make that in my GrailsUnitTestCase class but I am getting the error:
groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: class for class: malibu.server.Winner

Comment: @ArthurNeves Makes me wonder if the mockDomain version of your class has a less-intelligent constructor that doesn't exclude properties in a map argument that are not sensible to set.  You might turn to bindData (as suggested by jjczopek); you can include a list of properties to exclude in your call to bindData().

Comment: ok but should I call the method bindData in which class?! because GrailsUnitTestCase doesnt have that method!

Comment: @ArthurNeves Yeah, it seems bindData() is only available in controllers.  You likely have to write a special method to achieve the same effect in your unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
def par = Participant.get(0)
def winner = new Winner()
bindData(winner, par)
```